# Creating excel report with php and sending by email

Tags: php

I have this php that generates an excel file for me with php reading from a database. I would like to be able to email the excel (as an attachment). The problem is that I can only get the file download but when I get the email there is no attachment

Could you help me?

When the email arrives I have only this result, without any attachment (excel file):

--90215ae30d47b3d98d4505ee5035e618
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a MIME encoded message.
--90215ae30d47b3d98d4505ee5035e618
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

--90215ae30d47b3d98d4505ee5035e618
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;      name="test.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="test.xls"

MQkwMzAyMDE4NTIzCU1HTkdQUDg0QTE4QzM1MVcJTUFHTkFOTyBESSBTQU4gTElPICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgICAgIAlHSVVTRVBQRSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCQ==

--90215ae30d47b3d98d4505ee5035e618--

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
 
$db2 = db2_connect();
$sep = "\t";
 
echo "Pr0001 \t Cdclie \t CodFis \t \n ";

$data = "Select t1.Pr0001, t2.CDCLIE, t1.CODFIS FROM MYLIB.ANAGR001F AS t1"; 

$result = db2_exec($db2, $data);
 
while ($row = db2_fetch_both($result)) {
    $schema_insert = "";
    $schema_insert .= "$row[0]".$sep;
    $schema_insert .= "$row[1]".$sep;
    $schema_insert .= "$row[2]".$sep;
    
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    print(trim(str_replace(',', " ", $schema_insert)));
    print "\n";
}

file_put_contents('test.xls', $schema_insert);

$to = "yanez25@libero.it";
$from = "robert_tr13@libero.it";
$subject = "test mail";
$separator = md5(date('r', time()));
// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "test.xls";         
 
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('test.xls')));

// main header
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
 
$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;      name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename=\"".$filename."\"".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK";
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: _Please_ use a proper mailer library such as PHPMailer, instead of trying to assemble something as complex as a multipart email yourself.

Comment: Investigate the `PhpSpreadsheet` library if you want to create Excel files. It looks like you may be creating a tab separated file but naming it `.xls`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a problem of generating the Excel sheet, or of sending it as a proper attachment?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel when you have robust PHP libraries that do this for you.

Using `PHPMailer` which is one of the popular. You can send string attachment by adding it like so:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($attachment,$filename,$encoding,$type);
```

`$encoding` and `$type` are optional

You can check [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for the full configuration and settings and if you feel you need to be part of the invention, you can either contribute code or funding.